# PHP - GET request and HTML generator - Security Best Practices

Tags: php, html, security

I'm working in a project where I have to pass some GET requests to a PHP script, and it has to generate new HTML page according to parameters passed.

An example:
Variables passed via GET request:

```
    Title > 'example'
    Videoid > 'video-id' 
    type     > the type of the page (landing page, contact form, etc)
    output: landing page that has example as title, and post the tube video,etc.
```

The script then generates a landing page using these parameters.

As long the HTML is 'injected' in the page from PHP, 
I'm wondering what is the best solution from a security standpoint to realize that script.

Answer (score 1):

properly escape it, so you do not allow any evil javascript injections~ - 
this should work just fine:

```
<pre>
<?php
ob_start();
var_dump($_GET);
echo htmlentities(ob_get_clean(), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8', true);
?>
</pre>
```